# Convert raster byte[] image data to column Format in C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, raster, escpos

I'm trying to convert a byte array from an image that is in `Raster` format, which reads from left to right, to `Column` format, which reads from top to bottom.

The problem looks simple, we have two-dimensional array of bits (width/height of image). In `Raster` format, you read the bits from left to right, in `Column` format you read the bits from top to bottom.

I try to do this to support `Column` format printing of the `ESC/POS` protocol. I already have the image in `Raster` format, now I'm trying to convert it to `Column` format.

`ESC/POS` documentation of `Raster` printing:

- https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=70#gs_lparen_cl_fn67

`ESC/POS` documentation of the `Column` printing:

- https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=106#gs_lparen_cl_fn68
- https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=90

For the moment, I make the conversion by working on the bits directly with `BitArray`. This solution is not optimal, it would be necessary to work directly in `Byte` in my opinion.

```
private byte[] ConvertRasterToColumnFormat(byte[] rasterData, int width, int height)
{
    var finalHeight = height;
    while (finalHeight % 8 != 0) finalHeight++;

    var finalWidth = width;
    while (finalWidth % 8 != 0) finalWidth++;

    var rasterBitArray = new BitArray(rasterData);
    var columnBitArray = new BitArray(finalHeight * finalWidth);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            var rasterPosition = y * finalWidth;
            var columnPosition = x * finalHeight;

            rasterPosition += (x / 8) * 8;
            columnPosition += (y / 8) * 8;

            rasterPosition += 7 - x % 8;
            columnPosition += 7 - y % 8;

            var value = rasterBitArray[rasterPosition];
            columnBitArray[columnPosition] = value;
        }
    }

    var result = new byte[columnBitArray.Length / 8];
    columnBitArray.CopyTo(result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

.NET Fiddle with Tests: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NBRBgt

Does anyone have a more optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach could be to grab a 8x8 block of bits, transpose it using [bitboard techniques](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Flipping_Mirroring_and_Rotating#Anti-Diagonal), and then store the bytes of the result. It's not very pretty, but it avoids ever dealing with individual bits, and of course avoids `BitArray` (which is slow even among bit-by-bit approaches).

The following code passes your test cases, but probably should be tested better..

```
private static byte[] ConvertRasterToColumnFormat(byte[] rasterData, int width, int height)
{
    int h = height + 7 & -8;
    int w = (width + 7) >> 3;
    int hsmall = h >> 3;

    var result = new byte[h * w];

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 8)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            // grab 8x8 block of bits
            int i = x + w * y;
            ulong block = rasterData[i];
            if (i + w < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w] << 8;
            if (i + w * 2 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 2] << 16;
            if (i + w * 3 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 3] << 24;
            if (i + w * 4 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 4] << 32;
            if (i + w * 5 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 5] << 40;
            if (i + w * 6 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 6] << 48;
            if (i + w * 7 < rasterData.Length)
                block |= (ulong)rasterData[i + w * 7] << 56;

            // transpose 8x8
            // https://www.chessprogramming.org/Flipping_Mirroring_and_Rotating#Anti-Diagonal
            ulong t;
            const ulong k1 = 0xaa00aa00aa00aa00;
            const ulong k2 = 0xcccc0000cccc0000;
            const ulong k4 = 0xf0f0f0f00f0f0f0f;
            t = block ^ (block << 36);
            block ^= k4 & (t ^ (block >> 36));
            t = k2 & (block ^ (block << 18));
            block ^= t ^ (t >> 18);
            t = k1 & (block ^ (block << 9));
            block ^= t ^ (t >> 9);

            // write block to columns
            int j = (y >> 3) + h * x;
            result[j] = (byte)block;
            result[j + hsmall] = (byte)(block >> 8);
            result[j + hsmall * 2] = (byte)(block >> 16);
            result[j + hsmall * 3] = (byte)(block >> 24);
            result[j + hsmall * 4] = (byte)(block >> 32);
            result[j + hsmall * 5] = (byte)(block >> 40);
            result[j + hsmall * 6] = (byte)(block >> 48);
            result[j + hsmall * 7] = (byte)(block >> 56);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

A simple benchmark with my setup (Intel 4770K, x64, .NET Core 3.0) on a 256x256 array gave:

```
old: 1103 ticks
new:   56 ticks
```

So a pretty noticable difference.